# iAd Fill Rate - trying to always get ads to appear

Tags: ios, iad

I'm trying to test iAds on an app i'm developing. I've set the Fill rate in settings to 100% and the refresh is on 15 seconds, but the majority of the time i'm not getting ads

Have i missed doing something to get the 100% fill rate?

The errors i'm getting are

> Banner Not Loaded - Error: Error Domain=ADErrorDomain Code=0 "The
>   operation couldn’t be completed. Unknown error" UserInfo=0x1c5ec590
>   {ADInternalErrorCode=7, ADInternalErrorDomain=ADErrorDomain,
>   NSLocalizedFailureReason=Unknown error} 2013-09-17 14:09:13.534 Banner
>   Not Loaded - Error: Error Domain=ADErrorDomain Code=2 "The operation
>   couldn’t be completed. Loading throttled" UserInfo=0x1d875bc0
>   {ADInternalErrorCode=2, ADInternalErrorDomain=ADErrorDomain,
>   NSLocalizedFailureReason=Loading throttled}

I've aldo had this on occasion

> Error: Error Domain=ADErrorDomain Code=3 "The operation couldn’t be
>   completed. Ad inventory unavailable" UserInfo=0x1e02da00
>   {ADInternalErrorCode=3, ADInternalErrorDomain=ADErrorDomain,
>   NSLocalizedFailureReason=Ad inventory unavailable}

The ads are implemented using a singlton class. They appear on the first view controller but not any others (they give the above errors)

singleton .h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <iAd/iAd.h>

@interface mt_iAdSinglton : NSObject <ADBannerViewDelegate>{
    ADBannerView *adView;
    BOOL bannerIsVisible;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) ADBannerView *adView;

+(mt_iAdSinglton *)sharedAd;

-(void) attachAdToView:(UIView *)view;

@end
```

.m

```
#import "mt_iAdSinglton.h"

static mt_iAdSinglton *sharedAd = nil;

@implementation mt_iAdSinglton

@synthesize adView;

-(id)init{
    if (self) {
        if ([ADBannerView instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(initWithAdType:)]) {
            adView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithAdType:ADAdTypeBanner];
        } else {
            adView = [[ADBannerView alloc] init];
        }
        CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
        adView.frame = CGRectOffset(adView.frame, 0, screenBounds.size.height-50);
        adView.delegate = self;
    }
    return self;
}

- (BOOL)allowActionToRun
{
    return TRUE;
}

-(void) attachAdToView:(UIView *)view {
    if (bannerIsVisible) {
        [view addSubview:self.adView];
    }
}

-(void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner{
    [self.adView setHidden:NO];
    bannerIsVisible = YES;
    NSLog(@"Banner Loaded");
}

-(void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error{
    [self.adView setHidden:YES];
    bannerIsVisible = NO;
    NSLog(@"Banner Not Loaded - Error: %@", error);
}

+(mt_iAdSinglton *)sharedAd
{
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedAd = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedAd;
}

@end
```

Then implemented in the view controller as so
.h
    @property ADBannerView *adView;

.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad

{
    [super viewDidLoad];
     self.adView = [[mt_iAdSinglton sharedAd] adView];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    self.adView.frame = CGRectOffset(self.adView.frame, 0, -96.0f);
    [self.navigationController.view addSubview:self.adView];
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    self.adView.frame = CGRectOffset(self.adView.frame, 0, 96.0f);
    [self.adView removeFromSuperview];
}
```